# Maybe, a wrong in 4.6 Example of 0 Chapter of Do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Picture below is from the  19th page of Do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry. In my calculation,
$$
\det (d(\pi_2\circ \pi_1^{-1})) =\frac{\partial(y'_1,...,y'_n)}{\partial(y_1,...,y_n)}
$$
where , when $i\ne j$
$$
\frac{\partial y_i'}{\partial y_j}= \frac{-2 y_i y_j}{(\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2)^2}
$$
and when $i=j$
$$
\frac{\partial y_i'}{\partial y_i}= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2-2 y_i^2}{(\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2)^2}
$$
In fact, for general $n$, I can't know the sign of $\det (d(\pi_2\circ \pi_1^{-1}))$, but when $n=2$, it is negative. It means the $(R^n, \pi_1^{-1}), (R^n, \pi_2^{-1})$ are not same orientation. Whether I am right ?

> [image]

Comment: Maybe read Example 4.5 again? (Since that's what's he's referring to when he says “the simple criterion of the previous example”, and it explains precisely why it works even if the determinant is negative.)

Comment: @HansLundmark   I think the "family given"  is $\{(R^n, \pi_1^{-1}), (R^n, \pi_2^{-1})\}$ , but they have different orientation.  Therefore, the family given does not determine an orientation.

Comment: Oh, that's a good point, you may be right! Probably he didn't even think about checking the sign of the determinant, since the argument in Example 4.5 shows that it can be fixed if needed.